# Do not display duplicated posts on 2nd loop if 1st loop already displays the same posts in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building a dictionary website with laravel6.

And when a visitor search a keyword, 2 queries will run to find posts.

Controller.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
{     
    $keyword = $request->input('keyword');

    $query = Post::query();
    $query2 = Post::query();

    if(!empty($keyword)){


        $query->where('word','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
        $data = $query->orderby('word', 'DESC')->paginate(4);


        $query2->where('definition','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
        $data2 = $query2->orderby('definition', 'DESC')->paginate(4);


        return view('index')->with(['keyword' => $keyword])->with(['data' => $data])->with(['data2' => $data2]);
    }
}
```

Then, show 1st query & 2nd query result.

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $val)
<div class="post">
<h2>{{$val->word}}</h2>
<p>{{$val->definition}}</p>
</div>
@endforeach


@foreach($data2 as $val2)
<div class="post">
<h2>{{$val2->word}}</h2>
<p>{{$val2->definition}}</p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

The problem is, 2nd loop ($data2) shows duplicate posts of $data.
So how can I not display duplicate posts on $data2 loop?

I tried like:

```
@foreach($data2 as $val2)
@if($val2->id !== $val->id)
<div class="post">
<h2>{{$val2->word}}</h2>
<p>{{$val2->definition}}</p>
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

But didn't work. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest to declare an empty global array and push each word or id from first loop into that array. Then in second loop try to limit those records which are not in that global array from first loop. For that you will use `in_array` function of php in second loop.

Comment: Or another approach will be to make a collection from these two data variables, while making a collection you will remove it's duplicate values and pass that collection to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the pagination for queries the only solution is to implement code in the controller. In the second foreach of the view it is not possible to know all the values of the first foreach.

If I understand your question correctly, you can change your approach and use a single query.
In the controller you can write a query more or less like this:

```
$data  = Post::select('word', 'definition')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                $query->where('word', 'like', '%' . str_replace(' ', '%', $keyword) . '%')
                      ->orWhere('definition', 'like', '%' . str_replace(' ', '%', $keyword);
            })
           ->paginate(4);
```

You have no duplicate posts and you can also search with multiple words separated by a space (for multiple search the order of words must be that of the text).

**EDIT:**
This the solution with two query. The first query rest the same, the second query is filtered by the id list of the first query:

```
$listDataId = Post::where('word','like','%'.$keyword.'%')>orderby('word', 'DESC')->get()->pluck('id');

$query2->where('definition','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
$data2 = $query2->whereNotIn('id', listDataId)->orderby('definition', 'DESC')->paginate(4); // whereNotIn exclude the first query value
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to separate the query to get result separately.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do that with laravel's collection. As you might have noticed each query in laravel is a collection, so you can play with collections like you can search here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-merge**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{     
$keyword = $request->input('keyword');

$query = Post::query();
$query2 = Post::query();

if(!empty($keyword)){


    $query->where('word','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
    $data = $query->orderby('word', 'DESC')->paginate(4);


    $query2->where('definition','like','%'.$keyword.'%');
    $data2 = $query2->orderby('definition', 'DESC')->paginate(4);

    //collection starts here.
    //It will replace duplicate keys and will give you one collection
    $merged = $data->merge($data2);

    //Now you will have only one foreach loop in the view.
    return view('index')->with(['keyword' => $keyword])->with(['data' => $merged]);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but, I really need to separate 2 queries to get result separately. Your first comment "in_array" might be able to use. I'll try it.

Comment: Okay not a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
$query2->where('definition','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->where('word','not like','%'.$keyword.'%')
```